# Raphael zooming and panning very slow

Tags: svg, zooming, raphael

I am implementing a gradient heat map chart with zooming functionality, I would draw up to 100x100 matrix, though the size might vary a lot,

for smaller blocks zooming works perfectly fine but its dreadfully slow when I draw big matrix,

here is my http://jsfiddle.net/6BEET/

Could someone please suggest ways to improve efficient zooming, I would like to implement native zooming rather than using other libraries like `svg pan` or `raphael-zpd` as I need to support IE8 browser.

Comment: doesn't work for me, not sure if its a problem with jsfiddle, if it doesn't work for you, maybe try a jsbin

Comment: Just a thought... D3 has a robust svg zoom/pan object via mousewheel. Suppose for IE8 you could build a bunch of div/spans colored as needed. D3 can easily handle this. IE8 users could merely increase the broswer scale. Then the rest of the browsers could use svg.

Comment: I am not sure Ian, the link works for me,

Comment: I have a pretty heavy user base using IE8 and D3 is not compatible without supporting lib's and drawing these many blocks with scope of extension to more blocks, I ran into issues, hence using raphael.